# What are the odds of only winning a lottery once when there is a 1 in 3 chance of winning with each draw and you have 20 draws?

Tags: odds

Lottery chance to win is 1 in 3.
I have 20 changes.
I only win 1.
What is the statistical probability of this outcome?

Comment: Why is this question hard for you to answer? What help are you looking for?  What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a fair equally likely outcomes you can simply use the following:

$$\text{probability of an outcome} = \frac{\text{Number of ways it can happen}}{\text{Total number of outcomes}}$$

So if winning and losing were equally likely, there would be $20$ ways to win once and $2^{20}=1048576$ possible combinations of winning or losing.  So your probability would be $1.9\times 10^{-6}$.

When each event is not equally likely, you need to weight each of those possible outcomes.  The best method for doing this is using [Binomial Distributions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html).  Your probability will be:

P(exactly 1 win from 20 trials):

$$\binom{20}1\left(\frac13\right)^1\left(1-\frac13\right)^{20-1}= 20\times\frac13\times4.5\times10^{-4}=3\times10^{-3}.$$

As expected, this is more likely than winning only once in the situation when the probability of winning or losing is equal.  Also, try changing the $1/3$ in this last equation to $1/2$ and you will get the $1.9\times10^{-6}$.